# How to specify differerent inputs coming from a smart contract on Cardano Cli

Tags: plutus

I am currently testing a plutus script on cardano-cli, I need to use 2 inputs from a SC address that have different datum, how can I specify both  `--tx-in-datum-file` for the transaction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define multiple by reusing the same flag multiple times like so:

```
cardano-cli transaction build \
  --tx-in 123#0
  --tx-in-script-file SCRIPT_FILE1
  --tx-in-datum-file JSON_DATUM_FILE1
  --tx-in 456#0
  --tx-in-script-file SCRIPT_FILE2
  --tx-in-datum-file JSON_DATUM_FILE2
  {...}
```

You can see from the cardano-cli documentation notation that you can declare multiple tx-ins, datums and redeemers:

```
(--tx-in TX-IN
   [--tx-in-script-file FILE
      [
        ( --tx-in-datum-cbor-file CBOR FILE
           | --tx-in-datum-file JSON FILE
           | --tx-in-datum-value JSON VALUE
        )
        ( --tx-in-redeemer-cbor-file CBOR FILE
           | --tx-in-redeemer-file JSON FILE
           | --tx-in-redeemer-value JSON VALUE
        )
      ]
   ]
)
```

Inside your validator (onchain) code you can use `findDatum` to retrieve the respective datum by its hash or pattern matching.